# cannot change auto_increment_increment value in mysql

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a database whose one table started auto incrementing the values by 10. I never set that up explicitly but for some reason it is doing that. I tried to reset the auto_increment_increment value by 1 using following:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

But it doesn't change! I tried to do it using command line but still it doesn't do it.

One more thing, on my local machine auto_increment works fine (it is set to 1), but this is the problem on my server. When I used mysql on command line, i logged in as a "root" user.

Can somebody please suggest what could be wrong with my database? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks WoLpH for all your help.

I finally found out what was causing this problem! The value of auto_increment_increment was altered in **.\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini** file. That is why, even when i tried to replace it using the following query, it didn't change:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it's the auto increment value that's the problem here? If you insert a row in a transaction and rollback, it will also increment and you will never get the id back.

If your code is somehow inserting many rows and rolling them all back, than you'll see this behaviour too.

Comment: Thanks for replying. By rolling back do you mean delete them? I am just inserting the data, nothing else. One more thing, on my local machine this works fine, but the problem is on my server. Regards

Comment: @user427969: I mean starting a transaction, inserting, rolling back the transaction. But deletes could also cause this.

Comment: No, i just insert a record. There is no delete or update operation even.

Comment: Can you show the output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';` so we know what the current values are? :)